# Beam direct-runner slow BigQuery read

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have a very simple process which first step is to read a BigQuery Table

```
p.apply("BigQuery data load", BigQueryIO.read().usingStandardSql().fromQuery(BG_SELECT).withoutValidation().withoutResultFlattening())
```

This step take about 2/3 **minutes** to perform (about 1000 lines retreived) !
When I look BigQuery I see multiple lines linked to my query

```
10:54:37.703 BigQuery delete temp_
10:54:37.244 BigQuery delete temp_
10:54:35.492 BigQuery jobcompleted
10:54:34.802 BigQuery insert jobs 
10:54:22.081 BigQuery jobcompleted
10:52:33.812 BigQuery insert jobs 
10:52:33.106 BigQuery insert datas
10:52:32.410 BigQuery insert jobs
```

This 2 minutes for job completion is normal ?
(I have no parallel activity on bigquery)

How can I have better (normal !) performance ?

Comment: Maybe your query is complicated?

Comment: The query is very simple. It is just a simple select without any filter/join/group by...

Comment: How many columns?

Comment: 5 columns (not a lot !)

Comment: Do you use direct runner?

Comment: Yes and when using Dataflow runner the behaviour is the same 2/3 minutes to complete query.

Answer (score 1):

By default `BigQueryIO` uses `BATCH` priority. Batch mode queries are queued by BigQuery. These are started as soon as idle resources are available, usually within a few minutes.

You can explicitly set the priority to `INTERACTIVE`.

```
p.apply("BigQuery data load", BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
    .withQueryPriority(BigQueryIO.TypedRead.QueryPriority.INTERACTIVE)
    .usingStandardSql()
    .fromQuery(BG_SELECT)
    .withoutValidation()
    .withoutResultFlattening())
```

Interactive mode allows for BigQuery to execute the query as soon as possible.